# Reading CRAN archive.rds fails in Docker container

Tags: r, cran, nul

I am trying to install some specific versions of R packages inside a Docker image. To this end I have written a function that queries the archive.rds metadata of CRAN similar to this:

```
meta <- paste0(contrib.url(getOption("repos"), "source"), "/Meta/archive.rds")
con <- gzcon(url(meta, "rb"))
readRDS(con)
```

This works perfectly well on Windows 10 (Rstudio) and Debian Stretch (base R), but once I put it inside an r-base Docker image the following error is returned:

`Error in readRDS(con) : embedded nul in string: '\004\0\t\0\0\0'`

I am at a loss why this happens and how I can fix this? The only thing I can think of is locale, but this is UTF-8 everywhere (en_GB on the working systems, en_US inside Docker).

Comment: Are you certain that `"repos"` is exactly as you expect it to be? What is your version of R (in and out of the docker image)?

Comment: I'm running R 3.5.2 all over. `"repos"` defaults to the RStudio mirror on Windows, on Debian it is `https://cloud.r-project.org/` instead, but this makes no difference since I tested both everywhere. I can manually download archive.rds with curl inside the Docker just fine, it is really the parsing by `readRDS` that is the problem...

Comment: Interesting. Can you verify the file looks like you expect? If you `download.file` the link first, you can run `file.info("archive.rds")` and/or `system2("sha256sum", "archive.rds", stdout=TRUE)` on it to trim down *where* the problem occurs.

Comment: Thanks, excellent suggestion. Unfortunately...

On my Debian: `[1] "0b0c8001ea5f91cf597b16c154e19edfa568719d5c6fe8b7140dc4b83a60e1ba  archive.rds"`

On Docker: `[1] "0b0c8001ea5f91cf597b16c154e19edfa568719d5c6fe8b7140dc4b83a60e1ba  archive.rds"`

Comment: That's a good verification. That *suggests* (but not guarantees ... though that would be a highly-unlikely collision) that the file size is most likely the same, too. Okay, a brute-force dive: save the contents of `Sys.getenv()` in both, and then compare them to find omissions or differences.

Comment: I've put the output of both [here](https://pastebin.com/TAKzn97p). The Docker is a Drone CI image, which explains the first couple of rows there. Not sure what to make of the rest though...

Comment: The fields that appear different and (to me) interesting: LANG (and LANGUAGE in one), TERM, LC_ALL. Try mimcking, clearing, changing each of those in either environment to see if you can replicate behavior in the other. (I also note that `R_LIBS_USER` suggests R versions 3.5 versus 3.6. How confident are you that both are running 3.5.2?)

Comment: It might be useful for you to see all of the differences in case I missed one. To make it easier to compare the two (since I don't have the key/value list), I saved each to individual files and ran in a shell: `diff -uw <(sort PieterBulls_console.txt) <(sort PieterBulls_docker.txt) | sort -k 1.2 | less`.

Comment: As it turns out I was indeed running R 3.6.1 on my Debian, but this was not the cause - I cannot replicate the issue in the rocker/rstudio:3.5.2 Docker image. What's more, rocker/r-ver:3.5.2 also does not have this problem, although it has a very similar Sys.getenv(). I put both of them [here](https://pastebin.com/jLmjujKW) for reference. So, it seems that it is an issue specifically with the r-base Docker image...

Comment: That's interesting (and along the lines of what I suspected you'd find). I don't know how much more I can help ... short of grabbing the image myself and going at it ... which I don't have time to do at the moment. Are you in a good place with this patch?

Comment: Yes, switching from r-base to r-ver is no issue at all. Thank you for all the help!